# Variable between php and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

code:

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost", "bikemap", "pedalhard") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gpsdata");     
    $aData = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
        $aData[$row['idgpsdata']] = array($row);
        $json = json_encode($aData);
?>

    var json = "<?php echo $json; ?>";
    document.write(json.length);
    alert('half done');

    for(var x=0; x < json.length; x++) {
        document.write("<li>"+ x + " " + json[x]+ "</li>");
    }
```

Output of the code:

20

```
0 <
1 ?
2 p
3 h
4 p
5
6 e
7 c
8 h
9 o
10
11 $
12 j
13 s
14 o
15 n
16 ;
17
18 ?
19 >
```

if you take out the line numbers is:  `"<?php echo $json; ?>"`

Looks suspiciously like a line where I'm trying to transfer the php variable $json to javascript variable json.

I've tried every type of bracketry and quote to get this to work.  Anyone see any mistakes or have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that the PHP code is being executed? That is, are you requesting the page from a web server with PHP enabled or are you just opening the page from the file system in the browser?

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie I am running the code from a site hosted with PHP enabled.

Comment: @LorenZimmer, why don't you "view source" on the output of your script and show us that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines

Comment: @Brad this kind of development is new to me where would I "view source" from?

Comment: from mozilla:  [23:56:39.850] An unbalanced tree was written using document.write() causing data from the network to be reparsed. For more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Optimizing_Your_Pages_for_Speculative_Parsing @ http://98.169.0.140:8080/Map/trials/testii.html:5  is this what you were mentioning Brad?

Comment: The code is doing exactly what you programmed it too. What did you expect to see?

Comment: @Shomz I did try it without success thanks for the find though

Comment: @JamesAnderson I thought that it would pass the contents of the variable $json from the php script to var json in javascript.  I did not expect it to pass the text of the code to json in javascript.

Comment: Does it matter if this a part of aa javascript file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var json = {<?php echo $json; ?>};
```

or maybe

```
var json = eval("{<?php echo $json; ?>}");
```

Be sure your code is interpreted as php by the server. The file extension '.js' is usually not configured in this way.

If you want to embed your php file as a js, you'd better to rename it as .php and add the required header like that :

```
<?php
header("Content-type","text/javascript");
?>

var json = {<?php echo $json; ?>};
```

Comment: I needed just the php file to pass the variables

Answer (score 0):

You could try:-

```
var json = <? echo $json ?>;
```

You cannot execute php code inside the Javascript. Instead you must get php to write the relevent javascript code;

Answer (score 0):

You could do it other way, that is, put your javascript inside php:

```
echo "<script>
var json = $json; 
document.write(json.length);
alert('half done');

for(var x=0; x < json.length; x++) {
    document.write(\"<li>\"+ x + \" \" + json[x]+ \"</li>\");
}
</script>";
```